# Using the same connectionId for a client connecting to SignalR

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, owin, signalr-hub

I'm rather new to SignalR and I've hit a wall: I currently have an ASP.NET MVC app running on one server (users coming in and logging into the app with their credentials) and a SignalR hub which is running inside a Windows Service hosted on a different machine using OWIN and self hosting. I've managed to get my web app and SignalR hub to work together, client is connecting to the hub and is able to send/receive data to/from SignalR.

However, I would like my web app to always connect to SignalR for a specific user using the same connectionId - which I would prefer to be the userId (or something based on this). Since SignalR is self hosted, in the Context object available in the Hub implementation I don't have access to the User from my MVC app.
As far as I saw I can't set the connectionId from the client side (jQuery), but correct me if I'm wrong... so any ideas or suggestions on how I could achieve the desired behavior would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to configure custom connectionId's. It is however possible to address clients by userId and even provide your own [`IUserIdProvider`](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/mapping-users-to-connections#IUserIdProvider). Simply use `Clients.User(userId).myMethod()` instead of `Clients.Client(connectionId).myMethod()`.

If you don't provide your own `IUserIdProvider`, the default userId for a given client will be the value of `Context.User.Identity.Name` when said client invokes a Hub method.

Comment: as I already mentioned, my SignalR is running as self hosted inside a WIndows Service which is on a different machine. So, inside the SignalR Hub the User property of the Context is null as I don't have access to the asp.net pipeline. I saw examples online on how to implement custom id providers, but all where for SignalR implementations which were hosted with the asp.net mvc web app.

Comment: kind of solved the problem using your suggestion. My solution (for now... not sure if it's the best, but seems to work) is: in the jquery code before the $.connection.hub.start() method I set the QueryString $.connection.hub.qs = "id=myUniqueId"; Then I implemented IUserIdProvider in which I get the id from the QueryString and return it. I've registered this IUserIdProvider  implementation in the Startup class of the self hosted SignalR GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IUserIdProvider), () => new MyUserIdProvider()); In the hub I use Clients.User(userId).method() ...

Comment: @AndreiC just one question. Imagine if a user A logs in to the application from different machines and when user B initiates a ping to user A, which machine will get the ping? If not both then how does it work?

Comment: @Reddy Both machines user A logs in with would get the ping.

Comment: @halter73 Thanks, I know that's how it should work. But in my case it is not, So wanted to confirm. I am using Forms authentication for pinging from signalR ie : I pass Identity.Name (user email Id) for the signalR ping. And receive ping only in the latest logged in user.

Comment: Just a thought: doesn't this create a security hole if a user sets a spoofed user id in a request?